# Is it possible to install Apache Ambari on top of an existing cluster

Tags: ambari

We have an existing Hadoop cluster that is not managed by Ambari. Is it possible to install Apache Ambari on top of an existing Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 1):

No, Ambari must provision the cluster it's monitoring.

Ambari is designed around a Stack concept where each stack consists of several services. A stack definition is what allows Ambari to install, manage and monitor the services in the cluster.